# Why all characters' arms/legs in Adventure Time are so soft?

Tags: adventure-time

How can they be so long and soft and even make arms waves? Have they not got any bones?

The dog Jake has magic, so it's no problem that he has soft legs, but it doesn't make sense that Finn has soft wave arms:

[image: Finn waving his arms]

[image: Finn shirt design]

But it is still funny.

Comment: Why did you delete [this question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/23725/49) just to reask it anew? Keep in mind that you can always edit your questions if you need to make any corrections to them (see the little "edit" link under the question). Likewise can you easily undelete it with a similar link if you happen to accidentally delete it (or if you temporarily deleted it for revision purposes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is most likely artistic license based on the style of the show, which is sometimes called [Noodle People](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodlePeople):

> An art style in which characters are drawn with exaggeratedly long, thin torsos and limbs.

As the Western Animation Examples section mentions:

> - The general art style Adventure Time, though there are exceptions.
>
>   - Jake takes it Up to Eleven. Being able to change shape at will, he often moves his limbs in ways that imply he has no bones whatsoever.

Which nearly all the humanoid characters adhere to:

[image: Adventure Time characters]

It may also be a callback to the classic style of animation where characters always acted like this due to the limitations of animations, sometimes called [Rubber Hose Limbs](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RubberHoseLimbs):

> This is when a cartoon character moves without any visible elbows or knees, so his limbs aren't stiff, but rather, bendy, like rubber hoses.
>
> In cartoons made before the mid to late 1930s' or so, this was intentional, for practical reasons rather than artistic ones. It all started with Felix the Cat animators Otto Messmer and Bill Nolan, and it was meant to prevent the motion of the limbs in question from looking like they were drawn through a strobe light and flickering — the basic idea was that if you didn't draw joints, you could make absolutely sure that the limbs in one frame overlapped with where the limbs were in the last frame.
>
> **These days, this is a deliberate artistic decision** on the part of the animator — either to creep you out; **to create a fun, zany, or cute character**; or as a deliberate nod to the Golden Age Of Animation. In the early days, however, it was just how things were done.